# How to calculate total time taken

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to calculate total driving time excluding time between Pause and Resume Driving using sql query.

Here is the sample data:

```
Create Table Tracker 
(LocationID int,
RequestID int,
TrackingDatetime datetime,
Status varchar(30));
go

Insert into Tracker
values
(1, 22, '2019-06-17 14:10:00', 'Stop'),
(2, 22, '2019-06-17 14:08:00', 'Driving'),
(3, 22, '2019-06-17 14:06:00', 'Driving'),
(4, 22, '2019-06-17 14:04:00', 'Resume'),
(5, 22, '2019-06-17 14:02:00', 'Pause'),
(6, 22, '2019-06-17 14:00:00', 'Driving'),
(7, 22, '2019-06-17 13:58:00', 'Driving'),
(8, 22, '2019-06-17 13:56:00', 'Start');
```

Grid view of sample data:
[image]

Comment: Create table and data inserts would help, if possible use some [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/)

Comment: I have a table, It is just for sample of data. I want a query to calculate total time taken excluding time taken in between Pause and resume

Comment: Please have a look at: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example)

Answer (score 1):

This is how you should have mention in the question:

```
Create Table Tracker 
(LocationID int,
RequestID int,
TrackingDatetime datetime,
Status varchar(30));
go

Insert into Tracker
values
(1, 22, '2019-06-17 14:10:00', 'Stop'),
(2, 22, '2019-06-17 14:08:00', 'Driving'),
(3, 22, '2019-06-17 14:06:00', 'Driving'),
(4, 22, '2019-06-17 14:04:00', 'Resume'),
(5, 22, '2019-06-17 14:02:00', 'Pause'),
(6, 22, '2019-06-17 14:00:00', 'Driving'),
(7, 22, '2019-06-17 13:58:00', 'Driving'),
(8, 22, '2019-06-17 13:56:00', 'Start');
```

Following query that you can start with for desired result ([for test..](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=facc8ad2cefd160f6f749bfe7c17d6b6)):

```
WITH T as (
            select  LocationID,
                    RequestID,
                    TrackingDatetime,
                    CASE    WHEN Status = 'Resume' 
                            Then TrackingDatetime
                            Else LEAD(TrackingDatetime) OVER (PARTITION BY RequestID ORDER BY TrackingDatetime desc)
                    END as PrevTrackingTime,
                    Status,

                    ISNULL(DATEDIFF(minute,
                                (CASE   WHEN Status = 'Resume'  Then TrackingDatetime Else LEAD(TrackingDatetime) OVER (PARTITION BY RequestID ORDER BY TrackingDatetime desc) END), 
                                 TrackingDatetime
                            ), 0) as Duration_Minutes
            from Tracker
            )
select *, SUM (Duration_Minutes) over (order by TrackingDatetime) as Duration_Cumm
from T
```

Comment: Thanks for helping us, if I have multiple RequestID then how i have to write a query? Please help me for this

Comment: @VinodVerma, use `PARTITION BY` in `OVER` clause of `LEAD ()` function, which goes as `PARTITION BY RequestID ORDER BY TrackingDatetime desc`

Comment: SELECT ns.Name,pr.PatientName,convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, pr.DrivingStartTime, pr.DrivingStopTime)/86400)+'Days '+convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, pr.DrivingStartTime, pr.DrivingStopTime)% 86400/3600)+':'+convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, pr.DrivingStartTime, pr.DrivingStopTime)%3600/60)+':'+convert(varchar(5),(DateDiff(s, pr.DrivingStartTime,pr.DrivingStopTime)%60)) AS TotTravelTime
 FROM [NurseScheduleForPatientRequest] nspr
JOIN  [PatientRequest] pr ON nspr.PatientRequestId=pr.PatientRequestId
JOIN Nurse ns ON ns.NurseId=nspr.NurseId
WHERE CAST(pr.DrivingStartTime AS Date) > '2019-01-01'

Comment: Sir as I have write a query i want to use (convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, pr.DrivingStartTime, pr.DrivingStopTime)/86400)+'Days '+convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, pr.DrivingStartTime, pr.DrivingStopTime)% 86400/3600)+':'+convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, pr.DrivingStartTime, pr.DrivingStopTime)%3600/60)+':'+convert(varchar(5),(DateDiff(s, pr.DrivingStartTime,pr.DrivingStopTime)%60)) AS TotTravelTime) to calculate actual travel time.